# Dealing with Out-Of-Memory issue in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a total of 5566 annotations from a single JPG-file with dimensions (4864 pix width, 3648 pix height). I'm trying to use a pre-trained `ssd_inception_v2_coco`-model to build a model for my data set.

My data set contains annotations of grains and non-grains on a crop field. The annotations (via `labelImg`) are tiny with the smallest (non-grain) annotation being just 2x3 pixels in size. Most of the annotations are however about 20x20 pixels in size.

Here you can see my config-file:

```
# SSD with Inception v2 configuration for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
        reduce_boxes_in_lowest_layer: true
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 33
        width: 33
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 3
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_inception_v2'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 0
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 256
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "pre-trained-model/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 10000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

And here you can see my label map:

```
item {
    id: 1
    name: 'grain'
}

item {
    id: 2
    name: 'nograin'
}
```

Here you can see the output from Tensorflow after I run the command: `python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config`

Here are the last few output lines from Tensorflow before I get OOM-problem:

```
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from pre-trained-model/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from pre-trained-model/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
Killed
```

And here is my memory usage (total of 32GB RAM):

[image]

**My question is: How can I deal with this issue? Can this problem be avoided by altering the config-file? Or is there a way to reduce the model complexity so that all memory would not be consumed or something?**

**UPDATE-SOLUTION:** As suggested in the answer, I split my image into 48 smaller parts and now the training procedure is up and running!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"5566 annotations from a single JPG-file with dimensions (4864 pix width, 3648 pix height)" -- this is too large, you won't be able to do anything meaningful with the image of that size. Please, split it into the smaller images, according to the preferred image size of the network you're about to use, or 800x600 if you cannot decide yourself.

It might be better, if your image split overlap a little, like 100pixel on every size so you don't lose any annotations because they cross the frame border.

Once you have the image split, you won't have any problems with processing it with any latest neural network.

Comment: excellent, thank you very much for your help, so it's an image size issue. I will try this and report how it worked.

Comment: Hi, yes that did it! I split my image into 48 smaller parts and now it's up and running. Thank you!